# problem installing dotnet cli on Ubuntu

Tags: command-line, apt, package-management, dotnet

Hello I am trying to have `dotnet` command working on Ubuntu  and I am using following command

`sudo apt-get install dotnet-dev-1.0.0-preview2.1-003177`

but when I run the command it throws following error:

```
E: Unable to locate package dotnet-dev-1.0.0-preview1-002702a
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'dotnet-dev-1.0.0-preview1-002702a'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'dotnet-dev-1.0.0-preview1-002702a'
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Where are you getting the installation instructions from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dotnet package is not found in the default repository. You need to add it first.

For ubuntu 16.10:

`sudo sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://apt-mo.trafficmanager.net/repos/dotnet-release/ yakkety main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/dotnetdev.list'`

`sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 417A0893`

`sudo apt-get update`

As a side note: the dotnet 1.0.0 preview2 is quite old. The current version is 1.0.4

`sudo apt-get install dotnet-dev-1.0.4`

Good luck!

Comment: This problem is resolved but I have other errors which I am opening other thread for. Thanks for your comments.